# Inteliji showing ```_ <- ``` error for scala zio operator

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, zio

[image]
[image]

`<-` operator is working fine in basic for loop of zio but with the zip operator IntelliJ showing error.

Solution to solve the IntelliJ issue

Answer (score 3):

It's not IntelliJ, it's Scala.

This:

```scala
for {
  (a, b) <- foo
} yield ()
```

Does NOT translate to

```scala
foo.flatMap { case (a, b) =>
  ()
}
```

It translates to:

```scala
foo.withFilter {
  case (a, b) => true
  case _      => false
}.map {
  case (a, b) =>
    ()
}
```

By specification pattern matching in for-comprehension (here `(a, b) <- sth`) is not checked by compiler for exhaustiveness, so instead it uses `.withFilter` to filter out all values which cannot be pattern-matched with it, before using `.map`/`.flatMap`/`.foreach` with `case` to process them.

ZIO does not define `.withFiler` which is why compiler (and IntelliJ) complains. Because you have uncommented invalid code in 2 of your examples. In fact, many structures don't have it, since it doesn't make any sense for them to have some "default" way of filtering, and how would it work securely (e.g. `Future` fails when you filter out its value, giving you some unhelpful exception message. Failing manually with `Future.failure`  inside `.flatMap` would allow you to give it some meaningful error if you have to).

If you want to change this behavior use [better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for) compiler plugin. Or Scala 3 with `-source:future` flag. Alternatively, you can work around this issue with:

```scala
for {
  _ <- Console.printLine("test")
  result <- Random.nextUUID zip Console.readLine
  (uuid, name) = result
} yield ()
```

since `=` creates just a normal `val` and it doesn't get in your way of creating unchecked match and extraction.